# How to conditionally put a class on one selected element as opposed to adding a class to all of them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently having trouble with a React notepad project I am building. I tried to create a feature where clicking the notes itself would conditionally create a new class on each individual note and enlarge the note. It works but the content would be displayed the wrong way around. for example, I click on the third note that says 'John' and it gives me 'Tim'. Here is the code snippet.

```
export default function Sidebar() {
    const { notesContainer, setNotesContainer } = React.useContext(notesContext)
    function del(index) {
        const notesCopy = [...notesContainer]
        notesCopy.splice(index, 1)
        setNotesContainer(notesCopy)
    }
    const [selected, setSelect] = React.useState(false)
    function selectFunction(e, index) {
      if (e.target.id == index){
      setSelect(oldValue => !oldValue)}  
    }
    return <div>{notesContainer.map((note, index) => {
        return <div onClick={(e)=> selectFunction(e, index)} id={index} className={note-box ${selected ? 'selected' : ''}} key={index}>{note.notes}
            <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={()=> del(index)} key={index} icon={faCircleXmark } className='icon'/></div>   
    }) }</div>
}
```

I checked the dev tools and all of the mapped elements are selected, not just the one I selected even though my `selectfunction` function explicitly tells it to select it on the condition that the id and index match.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not selecting an individual item.

```js
selected ? 'selected' : '';
```

In this part, if `selected` is `true` then it is `true` for all items. And if it is `false` then it is `false` for all items.

So, instead of making the `selected` variable a `boolean`, make it store the selected id.

```
export default function Sidebar() {
    const { notesContainer, setNotesContainer } = React.useContext(notesContext)
    function del(index) {
        const notesCopy = [...notesContainer]
        notesCopy.splice(index, 1)
        setNotesContainer(notesCopy)
    }
    const [selected, setSelect] = React.useState(-1)
    function selectFunction(index) {
        setSelect(index)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {notesContainer.map((note, index) => {
                return (
                    <div
                        onClick={() => selectFunction(index)}
                        id={index}
                        className={`note-box ${
                            selected === index ? 'selected' : ''
                        }`}
                        key={index}
                    >
                        {note.notes}
                        <FontAwesomeIcon
                            onClick={() => del(index)}
                            key={index}
                            icon={faCircleXmark}
                            className="icon"
                        />
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```